Problema con método throwIf en Laravel
Hay muchas API con un mal diseño que informan un error estableciendo una propiedad en la respuesta con un boolean para informar el error o un código de error PERO responden 200 como código HTTP.
En este tipo de casos el método throwIf() de Http Client de Laravel (que internamente usa el método throw()) no funciona porque la excepción solo se genera si se cumple la condición de failed() y failed verifica que el código HTTP sea >=400.
¿Qué se podría hacer en estos casos donde existe error pero no ingresa por throwIf() por responder con 200?
public function throw()
{
    $callback = func_get_args()[0] ?? null;

    if ($this->failed()) {
        throw tap($this->toException(), function ($exception) use ($callback) {
            if ($callback && is_callable($callback)) {
                $callback($this, $exception);
            }
        });
    }

    return $this;
}


Buen día, entiendo tu caso, lo que yo hago es buscar específicamente si la propiedad o etiqueta de "error" viene en la respuesta y si trae datos, por ejemplo if isset($data['error']) && $data['error'].

Y tiras una excepción si la condición se cumple? Sin usar throw() o throwIf() no?

En mi caso yo cree alertas con dispatchBrowserEvent y envío una notificación que se despliega en la parte superior de la página para indicar al usuario que hubo un error, pero como el usuario no puede hacer prácticamente nada no le pongo el error exacto, solo un mensaje genérico. Pero depende lo que necesites hacer, podrías lanzar una excepción.
